# NuGet changes .ascx.cs folder location, giving reference errors in VS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

I am trying to make a NuGet package, with two .ascx and two .ascx.cs files. All four files are in the same folder, not in the app_code folder. Now when I make a Nuget package, it put's the .cs's inside the app_code folder, giving me the `"does not contain definition for...are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?"` error for the .cs files trying to reference controls on the .ascx. Now what I want to know is two things:

1. how can I make a reference from the .ascx.cs file to the .ascx when they're in different folders so I can program the controls again?
2. how can I override the folder location for .cs files with NuGet? I tried using the `<files>` tag like this:

   `<files><file src="somepath\*.ascx.cs" target="somepath"/></files>`

but when I open the package with 7zip and look at the .nuspec there, it appears NuGet just ignores that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the package structure look like before you create the package? are you using a content folder, etc.?

Comment: It's a widget for Blogengine.Net, they require the files to be in /wwwroot/widgets/widgetname/

Comment: Should be fixed in the next version of nuget (http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1144).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Taken from David Fowler's comment, so this can be marked as answered)*

This is [a bug in NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1144) and has now been fixed :-)